# Passing Parameter to Rest Client

Tags: rest, gwt, jersey

In my gwt application, I've implemented this method:

```
@Service("carService")
@Path("/cars")
@Scope("request")
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

     @Autowired
     private CarDAO carDAO;

     @Override
     @GET @Path("{type}/{start}/{end}")
     @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
     public List<Car> findByType(@PathParam("type") CarType type, 
                     @PathParam("start") Date start, 
                     @PathParam("end") Date end) {
     return carDAO.findByType(type, start, end);
     }
```

where findByType is a method in the carDAO asking to databases (in a peer-to-peer architecture) for available cars to rent. 
Now I have to implement its rest client and I have:

package it.unibo.ronf.server.rest;

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

import it.unibo.ronf.shared.entities.Car;
import it.unibo.ronf.shared.entities.CarType;

public class ClientRestCars {

public List<Car> findAvailableCar(CarType type, Date start, Date end) {

    Client client = Client.create();

    WebResource webResource = client
            .resource("http://localhost:8080/RONF/rest/cars");



}

}
```

and I don't know how to go on, how to pass the parameters to the url and get the list of cars as results.
Can help?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a framework to send your request, you should look at [restygwt](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html). It allows to create such requests in this way :

```
@PUT
@Path("{type}/{start}/{end}")
public void updateOrder(@PathParam("type") CarType carType,
                        @PathParam("start") Date start,
                        @PathParam("end") Date end,
                        MethodCallback<OrderConfirmation> callback);
```

Note : If you are using gwtp, you should note that they will soon provide this type of interface out-of-the-box.

Here is a quick example but you still should read the [user guide](http://restygwt.fusesource.org/documentation/restygwt-user-guide.html)

First, create a service (an interface which extends RestService):

```
@Path("/test/method")
public interface CarService extends RestService {

  /*
   * With @PathParam, you can specify the name of the attribute in the request.
   * Without PathParam, the name of the attribute takes the name of the argument.
   * The parameter type T of MethodCallBack<T> is the type you expect in the success method of the callback (see above)
   */
  @GET
  public void get(CarType carType,@PathParam("start")Date myStartDateWithASillyName, Date end,MethodCallback<List<Car>> callback);

  /*
   * Another method just to show that you are not limited to one...
   * Here, the request have car parameter and is intended to save a car.
   * As REST norms expect in this case, the resulting car is returned from server (with potentially the id updated after insert in database)
   */
  @POST
  public void post(Car car,MethodCallback<Car> callback);
}
```

Now, from anywhere in your code, you can call your service like this:

```
CarService service = GWT.create(CarService.class);
    service.get(carType,dateFrom,dateTo,new MethodCallback<List<Car>>() {

        /*
         *This method is called if a problems occurs (server not reachable, 404,403 etc)
         */
        public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
            Window.alert("Error x: " + exception);
        }

        /*
         * In case of success, this method is called and you obtain 
         * the expected List<Car> as the response parameter
         */
        public void onSuccess(Method method, List<Car> response) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: But the same works for GET? Causa I don't need to update anything, just to look for cars

Comment: Sorry for the PUT, I just took an example from the restygwt site and adapted it. Of course it works for POST, PUT, DELETE, GET etc

Comment: Thank you very much! Anyway as you told me, I'm actually using a framework to have the Rest service, it's jersey and it'd be necessary to work with it...

Comment: You are using Jersey on server side, don't you? restygwt is to be used on client side. In my team, we are using jersey on server side to read incoming request and we are using restygwt on client side to generate the requests

Comment: Yes, I use jersey server side. So with restygwt I can do request with objects (not primitive) as parameters? Sorry...I'm a very newbie to all this

Comment: Could you please write exactly How I should write my request to look for cars eith two Dates (start,end) and a class CarType?

Comment: I updated the code with a small example but you should really read the documentation, especially to understand how objects are mapped into JSON. For example, for dates, there is some config to do so that Jersey and RestyGWT format the date in the same way.

Comment: Forgive...I know I'm annoying. I'll read the documentation tomorrow. Thank you for being so kind. :)